# Sendmail has stopped working. Need advice with error message

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

So my server has stopped sending emails. Taking a look in `/var/mail/www-data` gave me some clues. The **Diagnostic-Code** shows this:

```
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 553 5.1.8 Sender address <www-data@ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal> domain does not exist
```

The rest of the error is as follows:

```
--s09He2kF031259.1389289202/ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Thu, 9 Jan 2014 17:39:55 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; me@mysite.co.uk
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.8
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 553 5.1.8 Sender address <www-data@ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal> domain does not exist
Last-Attempt-Date: Thu, 9 Jan 2014 17:40:02 GMT

--s09He2kF031259.1389289202/ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <www-data@ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal>
Received: from ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) with ESMTP id s09HdtkF031257
        for <me@mysite.co.uk>; Thu, 9 Jan 2014 17:39:55 GMT
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
        by ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id s09Hdtnu031256;
        Thu, 9 Jan 2014 17:39:55 GMT
Date: Thu, 9 Jan 2014 17:39:55 GMT
Message-Id: <201401099999.s09Hdtnu031256@ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal>
To: me@mysite.co.uk
Subject: New newsletter 
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:TemplateController.php
From: newsletters@mysite.co.uk
```

What I am finding strange is that nothing has changed on that server recently. The only think I have done is create an exact replica of the server so the sever currently has a clone running which means there is another server out there with the same hosts file. Could this be causing the issue?

My hosts file currently looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
54.444.222.44 test.answers.com answers
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is reported by commands `hostname` and `hostname --fqdn`?

Comment: Hostname: ip-10-33-164-999 /  hostname --fqdn: ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal

Comment: note: I have changed the last three numbers of my IP throughout this post to 999 so I dont expose my server to the world!

Answer (score 1):

Your sendmail uses ip-10-33-164-999.eu-east-1.compute.internal as its email name.  It uses it as default domain of local users,

The remote hosts refuse to accept messages with sender domain lacking public 'MX' or 'A' DNS records as it would be impossible to send back (eventual) bounce messages.

Do you have a static public IP address?

YES =>
Set your hostname to name with public `MX` or `A` DNS records

https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name

NO =>
You may make sendmail masquearde for email purposes as another host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems you are correct, however, when I change my hostname to the A DNS record (www.mysite.com) it stops my website from being served. I could send emails from the server though. I have setup a new A DNS record on a new subdomain (server.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com) and I will use that. Im just waiting for it to propagate so I will report back soon and let you know if its works.